# Emulator response is very slow

Tags: android, android-emulator

Emulator in android is very slow and at times it is not responding as well. Does emulator performace is dependent on system configurations?

Is there any other way to view the android app output other than emulator? Kindly please suggest me as emulator is wasting most of my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem with your environment, it is just that the emulator is very slow.

Practically I use a real phone to do my tests. It is faster and tests are more realistic. But if you want to test your application on a lot of different Android versions and don't want to buy several phones, you will have to use the emulator from time to time.

The Android SDK now alows to use an x86-based Android emulator. See http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm

**Try [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/). It's much faster than the Google Android emulator. Follow these steps:**

- Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).
- Download the [ISO file](http://www.android-x86.org/download) that you need.
- Create a virtual machine as Linux 2.6/Other Linux, 512 Mb RAM, HD 2
  GB. Network: PCnet-Fast III, attached to NAT. You can also use a
  bridged adapter, but you need a DHCP server in your environment.
- Install Android x86 on the emulator, run it.
- Press Alt+F1, type netcfg, remember the IP address, press Alt+F7.
- Run cmd on your Windows XP system, change the directory to your
  Android tools directory, type `adb connect <virtual_machine_IP>`.
- Start Eclipse, open the ADT plugin, find the device, and enjoy!

Comment: Don't shy away from upvoting the answer and marking the answer as resolved. This will help others who vist your thread and will benfit like you.

Comment: No.... actually it is no allowing me to mark as answered asking me to wait few more minutes

Comment: Hi Crusader... I have tried to install virtual box but couldn't find in link also I have seen many ISO files which one I need to download and install. Can you please eloborate more on this. I currently have HP laptop with AMD processor

Comment: I gave you the homepage link of virtualBox so that you get an idea what it is. There is [download section to download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Chech out [this link as well](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=33685982). watch [video for ref](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfWb_h96_-Q&feature=youtu.be)..phew.. what else.. Why don't you try first and let me know.

Comment: Sure let me try and will post my results here... Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Crusader.. I have download the windows package of virtualbox and tried to run but it is throwing error virtualbox is not a valid Win32 application, Also I have downloaded the ISO file android-x86-4.2-20130228.iso. Now can you guide me how to finish this. Thanks

Comment: Sure, please read page no 34 of [this pdf link](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.2.12/UserManual.pdf). you get fair bit of idea of its installation. ANd what about android-x86.. where are you stuck??

Comment: Actually I didn't extract the image file of android-x86... need to extract and move further... but still I am not confident with the installation will do it this weekend. If virtual box installation is done then how to make emulator run.. Sorry I am asking so many questions, I am new to android and this emulator is taking most of my time.

Comment: Its OK to ask questions. Look, you have go step by step mentioned above. You will have some difficulty understanding at first but its OK... You won't know if that good or not without trying.

Comment: Hi Crusader I have setup virtual box now when I run the command "adb connect IP" on my windows 7 then I am getting message "unable to connect to 10.0.2.15/24:5555" can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can speed up the emulator by running the Atom x86 system images instead of the ARM ones (since those CPU instructions need to be translated and thus is slower). Read more here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm

Comment: Thanks britzl.. Sure will try it.but will the exception logging is will be same as ARM or it differs?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by exception logging. If you mean logcat logging of exceptions thrown by apps then yes, it will be the same. I do not know about exceptions deep within the android framework. I would assume that it's the same. But if you're worried about things like that it would be much better to run on an actual device. I rarely use the emulator at all (and my choice has nothing to do with emulator speed)

Answer (score 0):

The android emulator is slow, can't do much about it. However Intel HAX can speed up your emulator speed significanly. HAX must be installed from your *android-sdk-direcotory*/extrax/
Then setup your emulator to use the correct system-image. Take a look at [intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-microsoft)

Comment: Thanks Ruben Weerts. I tried to install HAX but giving me some error also my system has AMD processor will it allow me to install intel HAX.. Please help me in resolving. Thanks.

Comment: From their website: `The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT)`. Wich means you need an Intel processor. Stupid of me not asking what processor you are using. Better follow the link CRUSADER provided to get optimal performance on your machine.

Comment: No problem Ruben Weerts... anyway thanks for your response and suggestions.