# Why Android simulator is so slow?

Tags: android, simulator

I'm using MAC PRO with quite powerful hardware(8G memory, SSD and i5). However, when I run the Android simulator, it's so slow(spent 2 minutes on start-up) and more worse, it response so slowly to mouse click.

Is there any wrong with my configuration? or anything I can do?
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: tats the way it is ..

Comment: ohh, emulator is slow not your prob, [check link for clarity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16434053/2345913). don't forget to upvote the answer if you like..

Answer (score 6):

You can switch to the x86 emulator images, as is described in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm). The ARM emulator images are closer to what most production hardware runs, as most Android devices have ARM CPUs. However, OS X machines use x86 CPUs, and converting between ARM instructions and x86 instructions on the fly adds quite a bit of overhead. The x86 emulator requires some initial setup, but then will give you much faster results.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your RAM. Bigger the size faster it'll be. you need to increase your ram.

Answer (score 0):

Using a real Android phone for testing is more reliable, some things don't work which does on an emulator, and most important, a real Android phone is much faster. If you don't have an Android phone you can try what the others said, increase the RAM size.